# Rspec test failure

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra

I am using RSpec to test my Chef cookbook. The unit test below fails. Can anyone help explain to me why?

**In recipe 2 I include recipe 1 as follows**

```
include_recipe ‘my_cookbook::client’
```

**Unit test**

```
it 'runs client recipe' do
  @chef_run.converge described_recipe
  expect(@chef_run).to include_recipe 'my_cookbook::client'
end
```

Comment: Did you try to redact things and miss the second recipe name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I experimented with including other recipes, I found the unit test ran ok. I then found the issue was caused by the fact that I had the following line in a helper method I was calling:

allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to receive(:include_recipe).with('my_cookbook::client')